# distinct row by a certain column with multple criterias and specific order

Tags: sql, mariadb, distinct

I've got one table

```
id(unique)  priority foreignId name
1           true     12        a
2           false    12        b
3           false    13        c
4           true     13        d
5           false    14        a
6           false    14        x
```

Now I just want distinct row for certain foreignId(s), e.g.

I want all rows for foreignId 12 & 14 "where foreignId in (12, 14)", the result should be

```
id(unique)  priority foreignId name
1           true     12        a
5           false    14        a
```

The logic here is that I just want the entry where priority is true. If there is no entry with priority, then it should just select the row with the lowest ID

2nd example for foreignId 13

```
id(unique)  priority foreignId name
4           true     13        d
```

Answer (score 1):

A CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` and the sorting that first comes true before false, you get you wanted answer

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (SELECT 
> `id`, `priority`, `foreignId`, `name`,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `foreignId` ORDER BY `priority` DESC) row_num
> FROM tabl1
> WHERE `foreignId` IN (12,14))
> SELECT `id`, `priority`, `foreignId`, `name` FROM CTE WHERE row_num = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | priority | foreignId | name
> -: | :------- | --------: | :---
>  1 | true     |        12 | a   
>  5 | false    |        14 | a
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (SELECT 
> `id`, `priority`, `foreignId`, `name`,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `foreignId` ORDER BY `priority` DESC) row_num
> FROM tabl1
> WHERE `foreignId` IN (13))
> SELECT `id`, `priority`, `foreignId`, `name` FROM CTE WHERE row_num = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | priority | foreignId | name
> -: | :------- | --------: | :---
>  4 | true     |        13 | d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=277682472eb55c283974efbf7abfb5df)*